# I can't send a custom Token back to client. // unity3d & firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions, token

I got a custom token after I start Debugging by following code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('C:/Node_firebase_Funcetion/Documents/generate_token/serviceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),});

var additionalClaims = { premiumAccount: true };

admin.auth().createCustomToken("j92C5KJtRQblKXRM0XUZzx4Jonm2", additionalClaims)
.then(function(customToken: any) {
  console.log(customToken); 
})
.catch(function(error: any) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I create a code to return data to client.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('C:/Node_firebase_Funcetion/Documents/generate_token/serviceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),});

 exports.Create_custom_tokens = functions.https.onCall((client) => {        
  console.log(client.user_ID);
  return {operationResult : "..Test..return.. data.."};
});
```

but there are something wrong,
When I running "firebase deploy" I getting results an error message.

```
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 8 function Create_custom_tokens(us-central1)...
!  functions[Create_custom_tokens(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'C:/Node_firebase_Funcetion/Documents/generate_token/serviceAccountKey.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/index.js:5:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        Create_custom_tokens


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:Create_custom_tokens

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions
Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
PS C:\Node_firebase_Funcetion>
```

it's work well if I remove :

```
const serviceAccount = require('C:/Node_firebase_Funcetion/Documents/generate_token/serviceAccountKey.json');
```

then using:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

in stand of:

```
"admin.initializeApp({credential:admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),});"
```

but i can't get custom token, because doesn't have serviceAccountKey.json. T0T

Comment: well other than thats not how you spell function, does "C:/Node_firebase_Funcetion/Documents/generate_token/serviceAccountKey.json" actually exist? the fact that it says not on running the deploy would suggest not

Comment: no problem about "serviceAccountKey.json" path,
until I " import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'; " 
then i can't running the "firebase deploy"

Comment: Well you have to work out why it cant read it.